# Accessing google maps in android emulator

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i am developing an android application using google maps data.I can access google maps in emulator but  when i try the same in my application the google maps is not opening .What is the problem?Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would try doing [this example](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

Check that your manifest has:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also remember that your view should have something like this:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key"
    />
```

You can get your map key from [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your not using the Google API in the emulator:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/

You need to create an Android Virtual Device (AVD) with the google API:
[image]

In the above screenshot you can see that 'test_avd' does not use the google API. 
Also you can see 'test_maps_avd' does use the google API.